# PSExec does not show output of the started child process (local machine)

Tags: windows, psexec, sysinternals

We are in the need of spawning processes from session 0 isolation to a logged in user in session 1. 
This task is done by using `psexec`, this happens entirely on the same machine, but I am unable to get the output of the child process to be displayed in psexec. Since this runs on a build-server I **don't want to redirect output to a file, etc**

Here is a sample call which does not work:

```
C:\>PsExec.exe cmd.exe -i 1 -u user -p pwd /C echo foo
```

The result shows nowhere any "foo"

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

cmd.exe exited with error code 0.
```

One thing that works, but is currently useless is to ommit `-i` and add `\\localhost`:

```
C:\>PsExec.exe  \\localhost cmd.exe  /C echo foo
```

returns:

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


foo
cmd.exe exited on localhost with error code 0.
```

But when I specify session 1, it breaks. This:

```
C:\>PsExec.exe cmd.exe -i 1 -u user -p pwd \\localhost /C echo foo
```

again shows no `foo` for me.

Again: The intention is not to `tee` or redirect `echo foo` into some file and then perform `type myfile.log` as a second step but to receive the output in the original psexec.

We are bound to session 1 as we need a Direct 3D context, having the service configured with "Allow interacting with the desktop" does not help here.

Comment: The command after "But when I specify session 1.." line seems to be incorrectly formatted/ordered, no? `cmd.exe` part should have been after `\\localhost`, and before `/C`. With its current format, your psexec parameters would be passed to cmd. I'm guessing you've just mistyped it in the question, and not in your tests...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that what you are asking is possible. `psexec -i` runs the process interactively on the *remote* machine, so everything including the console I/O happens in the respective session on the remote machine.

The `-i` behavior does in fact make sense. Suppose for example that you ran a batch file which required user input e.g. had a `pause` or `set /p`. With `-i` that input would need to be entered on the target machine, not on the machine where you run `psexec`. Similarly, the output goes (only) to the remote machine.

The other part of your question is the difference between `psexec \\localhost` and `psexec` without a computer name at all. This one appears to be an undocumented `psexec` quirk, which has been noticed and reported before, for example (with a bit of reading between the lines) at [Redirect output of process started locally with PSExec](https://superuser.com/questions/649550/redirect-output-of-process-started-locally-with-psexec).